# How do I build an array of form controls/groups in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, form-control, formgroups

I have a custom requirement where I have a list of inputs that need to sent to a form in a specific order.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
  <input  [value]= "item.name"></span>
  <select>
    <option [value] = 'color.name' *ngFor="let color of colors">{{color.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <tag-input theme='minimal'></tag-input>
</li>
```

How should I be organizing this into a form-group for these inputs? I Ideally want to get and array of `{'item': item_name, 'color': color_name, 'tags': [tag1, tag2, tag3]}`  as the parameters to be sent to my form.

Comment: have you considered using FormArray? check out the documentation here: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: hi yes, I am just a little confused as to how to use it in this case. I tried 
valForm = new FormGroup({
item : new FormArray([]),
color: new FormArray([]),
tags: new FormArray([])
})

Comment: I just want to find out how I can make it one array of hashes as stated above. I am just confused as to where to add the form Arrays and where to add form controls/ groups in order to get the output in this format {'item': item_name, 'color': color_name, 'tags': [tag1, tag2, tag3]}

Comment: in order to manipulate the way your data organized you can use (your form).getRawValue() then create an object in the wanted order. i don't think what you need is an array if i get you right

Comment: it is an array of these items - each of these inputs would repeat (items.length) times. Ideally, I am looking for an array to be built with each item of the array as the hash above. I am looking to do something like this but it does not work: valForm = new FormGroup({ all_items: new FormArray([ {item:new FormConrol, color: new FormControl,  tags: new FormArray[''] }]) })

Comment: u shouldn't wrap your FormArray(all_items) with an FormGroup try to do something like this: valForm = new FormArray([ {item:new FormConrol, color: new FormControl, tags: new FormArray[''] }])

Comment: Makes sense , but i get an error:  {item:new FormConrol, color: new FormControl, tags: new FormArray[''] } is not assignable to abstractcontrol. Anything I put inside the FormArray seems to cause issues.